# Deleted connection on IIS

Tags: iis-7, connection

I have upgraded Tomcat and compile Java code, everything worked fine until I accidentally deleted connection on IIS, however is still has all the old settings, but when I am trying to go to the Default Website I get 
Do you want to save index.jsp from localhost?

When I go to the directory below and I click browse prompst me to 
Do you want to save I*S* from local host?

Please provide any troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with JSP mapping
On IIS --> Handler Mapping --> ISAPI dll --> Edit Feature Permissions --> READ, WRITE, EXECUTE. It resolved my issue.